# Socket communication output issue

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, ip-address, tcplistener

In getting used to Sockets using Client server communication here is my code.

```
   //server partl
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); //use local m/c IP address, and use the same in the client

            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8020);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();


            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k = s.Receive(b);
            //Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");

            //Writes to label1
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                label1.Text = b[i].ToString();



            //ASCII endoing to use ACK.
            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");

            /* clean up */
            s.Close();
            myList.Stop();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + ex.StackTrace);
        }


        //Client part

        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

            tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8020); // use the ipaddress as in the server program

             Console.WriteLine("Connected");
             Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

             //gets the text from textbox
            String str = textBox1.Text;
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));


            tcpclnt.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + ex.StackTrace);
        }


    }
```

I am using a form to communicate on local host and writing a one .cs file and want to show the text(from textbox) from Client-labelled portion to the label on server-labelled portion.

Any idea why its not showing output?. New to sockets !!!

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's not showing anything because you are throwing away all errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When socket receives the data instead of loop simply use this:

```
if (k > 0)
    label1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
```

Also you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for simply send and receive data using TcpClient which is a wrapper around socket.